# How do NFCIP-1 (ECMA 340) and NFCIP-2 (ECMA 352) relate? Is 1 the minimum I need to use and 2 comes on top (optionally?) or does 2 replace 1?

Tags: nfc, iso, rfid, ecma

This previous post
[NFC standards (NFC Forum, ISO/IEC, ECMA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186887/nfc-standards-nfc-forum-iso-iec-ecma)

is helpful but does not anwer this question.

Thank you!